# Cantors Intersection theorem and convergence of cauchy sequences to more than one point in a metric superspace?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

As per the textbook-: metric spaces by Michael Searcoid:

> **Cantor's Intersection Theorem** : Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $F$ is a nest of non-empty subsets of $X$ for
>   which $\inf~\{diam~(A)~|~ A ∈ F\} = 0.$ Suppose $\bigcap~\{\bar A \}$= ∅. Then, given $z \notin  X, d$ can be extended to be a metric on $X' = X \bigcup \{z\}$ in such a way that $Cl_{X'} (A) = Cl_X(A) ~\bigcup ~\{z\}~~~ \forall A \in F$. Thus
>   $\bigcap \{Cl_{X'} (A) ~|~A ∈ F\} = {z}.$

Note $(i)~~\bar A = Cl_X (A) = $ Closure of $A$ in $X.~~~(ii)~~diam~(A) = \sup \{d(a,b)~|~a,b \in A\}$.

Now, Suppose $\{y_n\}$ is a cauchy sequence in $Y$ which does not converge in the metric space $Y$. Then, $\{y_n\}$ satisifies all the requirement of the cantor's intersection theorem. As per the theorem , it is possible to define several such points $z_1,z_2, \cdots , z_n$ such that $\{y_n\}$ converges to each of the points  $z_1,z_2, \cdots , z_n$ in the metric space $Y' = Y \bigcup \{z_1\}\bigcup \{z_2\}\bigcup \cdots\bigcup \{z_n\}$.

But how is it possible that a sequence can converge to more than one points.

Where could I be making a mistake? Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Where did you get this statement? This has very little to do with the [usual statement of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem#Variant_in_complete_metric_spaces).

Comment: @jose the textbook-: metric spaces by Michael searcoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot apply the theorem recursively. After having added one point $z_1$ to your space, the assertion that the intersection of the closures is not-empty fails ($z_1$ belongs to it) and therefore you cannot apply the theorem once again.

Comment: Thank you! missed that